# TextDecoder return empty string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, three.js, textdecoder

There is an `.stl` file with charset `us-ascii` which must decode as string.

```
static decodeText( array ) {

    // array is ArrayBuffer
    console.log( array.length ); // 621757404

    return new TextDecoder( ).decode( new Uint8Array( array ) );

}
```

But return empty string `""`. It's not occurs for every `array`. For some `.stl` file gotten this issue.

How can it be solved ?

```
Avoiding the `String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array)` shortcut, which
throws a "maximum call stack size exceeded" error for large arrays.
```

Comment: Perhaps array is 0 length. I bet there's an asynchronous reason you're passing an empty array to the function

Comment: No, `console.log( array.length ); // 621757404` array isn't empty. It's occur for some `.stl` files not for every file.

Comment: Obviously your browser can't handle 600mb file. Thanks for adding the extra info though

Comment: It was imported more than `600MB` which was `binary`. I tested on `chromium` in other system. The result was the same!

Comment: chromium is chromium on any system ... have you tried a non-chromium based browser? and `621757404` is actually LESS than 600MiB but more than 600MB ... so when I say 600MB, I'm still in the same ballpark - I wasn't going to say your browser can't handle exactly 621757404 bytes, was I

Comment: It's work correctly in `FireFox` ! :)

Comment: see what I mean that "your browser" may be the issue